# safest python encoding across platforms

Tags: python, encoding, cross-platform

I will have to run some python code across platforms.
What is the safest option in term of encoding for the source files?

I have noticed that:

```
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb 22 09:40:16 2017
"""
pycode
```

does not raise errors in Linux, while it does in Windows.
The following seems safer, why is that the case?

```
#!/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb 22 09:40:16 2017
"""
pycode
```

Comment: That's the case because windows doesn't actually work, it just sometimes gives impression that it does.

All python strings (and I mean actual Python, not boomer python that should have died the moment Python3, also known as the true and only **Python** came out) are encoded in unicode, and most of the time you should be using that in any case, if something doesn't support unicode, it probably shouldn't even exist in **[current year]**.

Comment: For Python 2, encode and declare source files as UTF-8, and be sure that they are saved as such if they are edited in environments where UTF-8 is not the default locale's encoding.  For Python 3, source file are assumed to be UTF-8 by default so no encoding declaration is required, but you should still take care that they are saved  correctly in non-UTF-8 locales.

Comment: interesting. Could you make it an answer?Also, is utf the safest?

Comment: guys, you should make an asnwer out of this

Comment: UTF-8 is safer in the sense that it can encode any unicode codepoint, whereas latin-1, as an 8-bit encoding, cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 source code is expected to be encoded as UTF-8 [by default](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/).  Therefore UTF-8 is the safest encoding to use for Python 3 code because developers do not have to remember to do anything - such as declaring a spec

- it's the default, so developers do not need to remember to declare an explicit encoding
- it can encode any unicode codepoint, so there is (theoretically) no risk that a developer might use a different encoding in a particular source to include a particular character

However, if the source code is edited on systems where UTF-8 is not the default encoding, developers must take care to ensure that the source is saved as UTF-8.

The same applies to Python 2, save that declaring the encoding is required if UTF-8 is to be used.

Having a reasonably comprehensive test suite would greatly reduce the risk of wrongly-encoded source files, as importing such a file will raise a `SyntaxError`.  If the code lacks tests, it would not be difficult to write a script that searched for `.py` files, tried to open them specifying UTF-8 as the encoding, and reported any that raised `UnicodeDecodeError`